# Load higher quality smooth streaming bitrate on start

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend, smooth-streaming, smooth-streaming-player

Is it possible to adjust the way in which smooth streaming xap bitrate is first started? As it is right now, the player shows a low quality stream until is has buffered the higher quality. Can I change this to allow for the higher quality on start? If so, how?

(I've already seen this question, but I am not using the media platform player.)

[IIS Smooth streaming low quality on start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189741/iis-smooth-streaming-low-quality-on-start)

Answer (score 3):

The answer on you link answers your question. All that you need is to replace the plugin by properties and events of the [SmoothStreamingMediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.media.smoothstreaming.smoothstreamingmediaelement%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class.

Though I don't like that implementation and msdn has a better example
[Select and Monitor Bitrate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182017%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

So in order to set the quality above average use this code:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    mediaElement.ManifestReady += OnManifestReady;
}

void OnManifestReady(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (SegmentInfo segment in mediaElement.ManifestInfo.Segments)
    {
        var videoStream = segment.AvailableStreams.First(i => i.Type == MediaStreamType.Video);
        var averageBitrate = videoStream.AvailableTracks.Average(t => (double)t.Bitrate); // you can use Max as well

        var allowedTracks = videoStream.AvailableTracks.Where(ti => ti.Bitrate >= averageBitrate).ToList();
        videoStream.SelectTracks(allowedTracks, false);
    }
}
```