# Select smooth streaming bitrate while playing csm-files

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend, smooth-streaming, smf, smooth-streaming-player

There are examples for switching bitrates: [Load higher quality smooth streaming bitrate on start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380959/load-higher-quality-smooth-streaming-bitrate-on-start), [IIS Smooth streaming low quality on start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189741/iis-smooth-streaming-low-quality-on-start) for SmoothStreamingMediaElement and SMFPlayer.

They work fine for .ism files. But they don't for .csm (composite manifests).
Segment.AvailableStreams and Segment.SelectedStreams collections are empty. And it looks like SetVideoBitrateRange doesn't do anything.

Is there a way for user to select a bitrate while playing a composite manifest?

Comment: I do not have an answer for you but I do have some advice: composite manifests are a rather badly supported technology and I recommend you avoid them as much as possible. They were something of an experiment that did not survive the test of reality and never matured into a reliable feature. DASH is resurrecting the idea but only time will tell if with more success (so far, not).

Comment: Is it possible to create playlists using DASH (mpd) files?

Comment: For each file in a playlist I need to specify begin time and end time. Also I need a player that allows to manually switch bitrates and show a single slider (position timeline) with an option to seek. For now I am using a custom CSM-playlist generator and customized player. I am using a generator to regenerate the playlist when a user switches the bitrate. The generated playlist contains only the tracks that matches the selected quality level. Then the player load that playlist and restores it`s position. Not to "smooth", of course.